# Zend Framework 2 CMS file structure

Tags: content-management-system, zend-framework2, directory-structure

I'm trying to build a simple content management system based on the Zend Framework 2. The problem is that I don't know how should the folders structure be like.

Until now I have to solutions in mind:

A. Building a general "Admin" module that has multiple controllers like Login Controller, Pages Controller, Posts Controller, each of this controller with his own actions.

B. Building an module for each component, like: Pages Module that has an adminController an an frontendController.

I'm sure that none of the above solution is the corect one, but couldn't find any solid solution or books to provide one. I've taken a look at gotCMS but noticed that this one i.e, saves all the data like layout views in the database, and this is not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it's a very first alpha solution, I work on [ensemble](http://ensemble.github.com) which is what I'd rather call a content management *framework*.

Ensemble's admin runs on ZfcAdmin. So you can drop in a Blog module which just has a admin controller under ZfcAdmin's route. But you can also manage pages (like texts) with a navigational page structure. All content parts (text, blog, etc) are separate modules.

So I'd suggest you take a look at the [sample application](https://github.com/ensemble/SampleApplication) and you can check out our [blog](https://github.com/Soflomo/Blog) as well, which just hooks in into ensemble. I know currently the documentation is scarce, but if we reach kinda beta stability we will focus more on docs.

The main benefits for "your system B" is you can drop in modules when needed. They all provide their own config, controllers, models and views. It's easy to install them from a developers perspective (load in composer, enable in application config) and you can easily override any view with your own ones.

**TL;DR:** choose structure B and have a look at Ensemble.

/edit: seeing you comment on Sam's answer: yes you have to do that. In ensemble, you specify a [route config for the frontend](https://github.com/Soflomo/Blog/blob/master/config/module.config.php#L66-L130) and create your admin routes as [child routes of ZfcAdmin](https://github.com/Soflomo/Blog/blob/master/config/module.config.php#L137-L208). For both the frontend as the backend you have [separate controllers](https://github.com/Soflomo/Blog/blob/master/config/module.config.php#L257-L258).

Comment: I followed the instructions on github, cloned the Ensable SampleApplication run php composer.phar install but i get "The process "git clone "git://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule.git" "D:\xampp\htdocs\SampleApplication\vendor\doctrine/doctrine-orm-module" && cd  /D "D:\xampp\htdocs\SampleApplication\vendor\doctrine/doctrine-orm-module" && git remote add composer "git://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule.git" && git fetch composer" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.

Comment: And this is the error message i get accessing the app "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to load ZF2. Run `php composer.phar install` or define a ZF2_PATH environment variable.' in D:\xampp\htdocs\SampleApplication\init_autoloader.php:32 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\SampleApplication\public\index.php(9): include() #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\SampleApplication\init_autoloader.php on line 32"

Comment: Ok, after another try all the dependencies seems to be loaded but i get the following error: "Notice: Undefined index: cmf_routes in D:\xampp\htdocs\SampleApplication2\vendor\ensemble\kernel\config\services.config.php on line 152 
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Ensemble\Kernel\Parser\Route::setModuleRoutes() must be of the type array, null given, called in D:\xampp\htdocs\SampleApplication2\vendor\ensemble\kernel\config\services.config.php on line 155 and defined in D:\xampp\htdocs\SampleApplication2\vendor\ensemble\kernel\src\Kernel\Parser\Route.php on line 62"

Comment: it seems there is something in  'Ensemble\Kernel', if i remove it from the application.config.php the admin panel works.

Comment: @TudorRavoiu the sample hasn't been updated quite a while. My fault, let me check it out and I'll post an update here asap

Comment: @TudorRavoiu you were right. Please update the repository (`git pull --ff-only origin master`) and then update composer (`php composer.phar install`). Then delete your database, re-create it again and import the `scheme.sql` and `fixture.sql`. I just fixed the problems.

Comment: I saw this on github right now :) Ok i'll do that, but don't know if this was really the issue because i figured it out before that schema has to be imported before fixtures and i did this from the beginning. but anyway i'll give it a try and give you an update in a few minutes.

Comment: @TudorRavoiu there were a few problems: 1) the ensemble packages weren't up2date (so the composer.lock is now new) 2) the db didn't contain the visibility flag for pages, so there was no navigation and 3) the readme said you had to do fixtures first and then load the scheme (doh, stupid)

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now! I guess that for editing the subpages i will have to create my own controllers, no? Because in the admin panel i can't find any editing options only the default zfc-admin text.

Comment: The homepage is a "non managable page" but the "about" and "sub" are. If you visit `/admin/page/open/2` you see a textarea. The Simple module (under `module/Simple`) is an example how you create a controller to display a text on the frontend side and another controller for a form on the backend.

Comment: Maybe i'm doing something wrong but this works for me only if i add the EnsambleAdmin module.

Comment: If i don't copy the EnsambleAdmin module and enable it in the application.config.php all i get is a 404 page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38163/discussion-between-tudor-ravoiu-and-jurian-sluiman)

Comment: ok, nevermind. after looking more into the file structure i get it now. please give me your address so that i can send you 100 beers :). Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

There is no right or wrong when it comes to building something new. Personally I'd go with B. I wouldn't even name the Controllers like you did (I'd break them down a lot more, like NewsAddController, NewsEditController, NewsDetailsController, etc...). Then I'd have an AdminModule that would simply display a new Layout with a specific "AdminNavigation". This AdminNavigation can be filled via the other Modules (i.e. NewsModule would inject it's own administrative Routes into the AdminNavigation via module.config.php)

Comment: so if I go with B, than in each module in the module.config.php configuration I will have to build the routs for each backend or frontend functionallity.
NewsDetailsCOntroller routes to main 
NewsEditController routes to admin ?

Comment: Partially. Both Edit and Details route to the NewsModule. What changes is the Layout.